# Does JRS-223 cover the runtime environment?

Tags: java, jython, jsr223

Does JSR-223 cover the specs of the interactive interpreter that is common on all kinds of compliant languages from abcl to rhino to jython?

If not, then do all these languages make their environments any way they want in Java, or are they mostly written in their own language (as libraries)?

For eg: is the python interactive interpreter written in python, or in C/Java/C#, depending on where it's running?

---

EDIT:

I'm not saying that EVERY scripting language NEEDS a REPL, but that every JVM-based scripting language that I have seen till date has one.
If specifications have not been established for a standard REPL environment, then maybe it is time to do so.

Comment: Huh?  I don't think JSR223 has anything to do with interactive interpreters (i.e. the read/eval/print loop).  It just provides a framework for embedding scripting languages into the JVM.

Comment: so the repl is implemented differently by everyone?

Comment: Who says that embedded scripting languages need a REPL?

Answer (score 1):

#### No, [JSR 223](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=223) has nothing to do with the [read-eval-print loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop).

Moreover, JSR 223 doesn't even say how embedded scripting engines must be implemented, it only provides a common interface.

**[Edit]** The closest thing to "covering the environment" is probably some of the [`ScriptEngine` static fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#field_summary) which allow Java programs to specify things like positional arguments (ARGV) and emulating the "filename" of what is being executed.

See the [`javax.script` package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/package-summary.html) to start learning about the Java Scripting API.

Comment: could you elaborate on 'common interface'?